# убрать пробелы перед знаками препинания python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

По заданию необходимо убрать лишние пробелы, т.е повторяющиеся и перед знаками препинания. С первыми разобралась, а вот со вторыми пока нет. Пробовала и через регулярные сделать и через сплит, но, очевидно что-то не совсем так)

```
import re
predl= str(input('enter the string\n'))
predl.split('\W+')
''.join(predl.split())
print(re.sub(r'\s+' , ' ', predl))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#string.punctuation):

```
import string
import re


In [108]: s = 'Hello , World ! Spam : Eggs ! ?  ; Ni !'

In [109]: pat = "\s+([{}]+)".format(re.escape(string.punctuation))

In [110]: res = re.sub("\s{2,}", " ", re.sub(pat, r"\1", s))

In [111]: res
Out[111]: 'Hello, World! Spam: Eggs!?; Ni!'
```

PS тестовую строку я позаимствовал из ответа @nomnoms12

Answer (score 1):

В простом случае Вам может помочь это регулярное выражение: `\s+(?=(?:[,.?!:;…]))`

***Пример:***

```py
import re


string = 'Hello , World ! Spam : Eggs ! ? … ; Ni !'
res = re.sub(r'\s+(?=(?:[,.?!:;…]))', r'', string)

print(res)
```

*stdout:*

```html
Hello, World! Spam: Eggs!?…; Ni!
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы не могли бы объяснить знаки вопроса в это части?    "(?=(?:[,.?!:;…]))"

Comment: уже нашла в документации, спасибо большое